# Can ant build.xml build target from a variable anount of input files

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

First excuse my bad English.

Here is the concept:
I have to implement multiple xslt transformations.
How many transformations shall be executed, depends on how many xml files will be in a separate directory/folder. So the problem is: How to tetll the build.xml (the ant build file) to do a loop that iterates a task for each file in a directory.
This is meta code is an attempt to describe the idea:

```
 foreach(test-cases/*.xml)
 {
       <xslt
         in="." out="report_(n+1).xml" style="ConstantStylesheet.xslt">
       </xslt>
 }
```

The stylesheet will not change per transformations, only the input and the output files.

`in="."` refers to the coherent xml file as an input for the xslt processor.

`report_${.}.xml` is to tell the processor that the output file name will be  suffixed with subsequent name of the input file.
If I specify same output for each transformation the output file will be overwritten each iteration.
If it is not possible in build.xml(the ant script), any ideas are very much wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `xslt` task https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html allows you to specify a directory with e.g. `<xslt basedir="test-cases" destdir="result-cases" style="ConstantStylesheet.xslt"/>`.

Comment: Does it mean that ant will do as many transformations as the files in the basedir are?

Comment: As far as I understand that, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much  @Martin. 
What if the stylesheet  is the input file itself? As if in the above example to substitute the  `ConstantStylesheet.xsl` with `test-cases`.